# Why does this code generate the error: "unparseable date"

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I'm trying to use the SimpleDateFormat class to parse a DateTime out of this string:

```
Mon Jan 10 2011 01:15:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

I tried the following format string:

```
String example = "Mon Jan 10 2011 01:15:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E M d y H:m:s z");
try
{
    Date exampleDate = formatter.parse(example);
    LOGGER.warn(exampleDate.toString());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    LOGGER.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

But it generates the error:

```
Unparseable date: "Mon Jan 10 2011 01:15:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)"
```

So I tried removing the parenthesized end part of the example string:

```
String example = "Sun Jan 09 2011 22:00:00 GMT+0000";
```

But it generates the same error.

```
WARNING: Unparseable date: "Sun Jan 09 2011 22:00:00 GMT+0000"
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Jan 09 2011 22:00:00 GMT+0000"
```

Any hints on how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html the format needs to be:

```
"E M d y H:m:s zZ"
```

This includes the general timezone and the RFC 822 time zone.

Or you could change your input date to:

```
Mon Jan 10 2011 01:15:00 GMT+00:00
```

which would accomodate just `z`.

(Note the colon in the last part.)

Answer (score 2):

You should use (or `Z` only for last part):

```
E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to use "MMM" if you want to parse textual months. From the javadocs:

"Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; otherwise, it is interpreted as a number."

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that the problem is that the `z` modifier can't parse `GMT+0000`.  According to [the Javadoc describing what `z` parses](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone), the format is something like GMT+HH:MM, rather than GMT+HHMM.  If you want to parse what you have, you probably want to change your format string from

```
E M d y H:m:s z
```

to

```
E M d y H:m:s 'G'M'Tz
```